# Play the video on mouseover - woocommerce platform

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to woocommerce / wordpress, and I will be grateful if someone can help me on this.
I created a new website using Mystile woocommerce theme. The website is to sell images / videos. Where I got stuck is , I want to play the video, when you mouse over the thumbnails on videos page. (similar effect that they use on [this website](http://www.gettyimages.ae/search/2/film?phrase=education)). Please let me know the procedure for this? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: what is your page link ? what you have done so far

Comment: Please refer this. There is a similar feature. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/0o8tt2z8/2/

Comment: Dear Rahul, Thank you for the link, but my issue is I don't know how to use this on woocommerce platform? all the videos will be added as digital products on the website. Could you please help me on this? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
<video poster="image.jpg" src="video.webm" id="id0" width="300" onMouseOver="id0.play()" onMouseOut="id0.pause()" onclick="window.location='video.webm';id0.pause()" loop title="video.webm
" ></video>
```

Comment: Dear Sarath, Thank you for the reply, But I need a way to do this on woocommerce platform. because all the videos will be added as digital products. I wanna know which coding part I should edit for this? can u assist me on this? Thanks a lot

Comment: adding videos as products?

Comment: yes, this web site is to sell videos and images, I will add the videos and images thumbnails via the woocommerce platform. When user visit the videos pages , I want them to play the video when they mouse over the thumbnail.

Comment: Dear Sarath, Thanks a lot , this code works for me, but how can I add this coding to the featured image of the product? I want this to be the thumbnail of the video? Kindly help me, Thanks

Comment: did you  tried to set    poster="image.jpg"    as featured image . ? if it helps mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

sample Html

```
<div class="thumbail">
<video preload="auto" loop>
    <source src="videos/movie.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="videos/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="videos/movie.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
</div>
```

and play video on mouse hover using javascript

`play` is not a jQuery function but a function of the DOM element. You therefore need to call it upon the DOM element.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".thumbnail").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).children("video").get(0).play();
    }, function() {
       $(this).children("video").get(0).pause();
        $(this).children("video").get(0).currentTime = 0;
    });
});
```

Note: `get` use for getting the native DOM element from the jQuery selection.

Try this..

Comment: Dear V P, Thank you for the reply, Kindly let me know How can I include this on wordpress / woocommerce platform ? The videos are added as digital products on the website. Since I'm new to this platform I don't know  where I should added these? thanks a lot in advance